# LSAG implementation in Python

Tags: signature

## Context

I am implementing LSAG in python because I do not find a non-obviously insecure implementation. I am not a cryptographer myself, thus simplicity is key.

The famous *Linkable Spontaneous Anonymous Group Signature for Ad Hoc Groups* paper states these algorithm parameters:

Parameters:

1. group `G` of prime order `q`
2. hash-function `H1 : {0,1}* --> Z_q`
3. hash-function `H2 : {0,1}* --> G`

Requirements:

- discrete log problem over `G` must be hard
- `H1` and `H2` must be **some statistically independent cryptographic hash functions**

## Proposed:

- Hashes onto elliptic curves are hard, so I use G = Z mod n with g=suff large prime.
- the thought with g suff large and prime is that i) each exponent yields overflow and thus cryptosecurity and ii) each integer in [0,n) is attainable via the generator.
- Since the order q of G is needed, I choose n prime and obtain q=n-1.
- Since H1 and H2 must be uncorrelated, I simply pick `H1=sha512(x)[0:256]` and `H2=sha512(x)[256:512]`. If the bits of sha512 were correlated then it would be a stupid algorithm. I suppose it is not. Hence this choice should be save. Also, each

## Questions:

- q is not prime. Does this result in security issues? (property was no-where used in the security analysis)
- There exist d in N such that `g^d % n = H2(message)`. This can break anonymity of the ring-signature when someone is able to brute-force d. It would be beneficial if the image of H2 was disjoint to the span of the generator, hence no d exists. Is there a way to construct G accordingly as a ring?
- EC would be more efficient and secure. Is anyone aware of an implementation of LSAG in python or of triplets for G,H1,H2 (i.e., code) that yield the purpose?

Comment: Monero used to use something called MLSAG, which is a generalization of LSAG that uses Ed25519. There is some Python code for it (which I don't think had a rigorous security audit) here: https://github.com/monero-project/mininero/blob/master/MLSAG.py Hashing to a group element is implemented with the function name "hashToPoint_cn". You can find exact instructions for implementation of an LSAG here: https://www.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-2-0-0.pdf on page 30.

Comment: I know one shall not thank in comments. But thank you massively for that!!!! I was hustling the information for weeks. This is tremendously useful.

Comment: @knaccc : Are you able to make accessible the "hashToPoint_cn" function?
I actually do not find it in the repository, nor on github. I see that it is called but I do not find a definition of it.

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/monero-project/mininero/blob/c5fcee9d8ec8c302bca7fda8ce79b68e20d31c34/mininero.py#L238. Also note: this is implemented to match Monero's implementation, which went to great lengths to be high-performance. There are much easier ways to do hash-to-point, such as simply taking a 256-bit hash, interpreting the result as a compressed point coordinate, incrementing it if you have an invalid point (50% chance), then multiplying it by 8 to ensure it's in the correct subgroup

Comment: @knaccc: thank you a lot. Yes, once performance becomes a problem I will probably want to keep this in mind. For now, I have actually opted back towards discrete log and found a way with quadratic residues to make sure a point lives in the ring.